# Show $\forall h\in H,\forall g\in G, ghg^{-1}＝h$ is not definition of normal subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be subgroup of $G$.
$H$ is normal subgroup if only if

$$\forall h\in H,\forall g\in G, ghg^{-1}\in H.\tag{1}$$

I want to know a lot of examples $H$ which does not satisfy

$$\forall h\in H,\forall g\in G, ghg^{-1}＝h\tag{2}$$

Also, if there are some name known as the name of subgroup $H$ which satisfies $(2)$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The set of all $h$ satisfying (2) is the *centre* of the group.  So $H$ would be a subgroup of the centre.

Comment: 2. Means that $H$ is a central subgroup. Examples are all non-abelian groups $G$, $H=G$, and all dihedral groups with $2n$ elements, $n$ odd, and all their non-trivial subgroups $H$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your statement (2)
H is subgroup of Centre of G ( called as Central Subgroup).
But to be normal ,H is not necessarily subgroup of centre

As a example ,you can take A3 (set of all even permutations) in S3 ( set of all permutations on three symbols).

More over, You can also take Sn (n≥3) .
In which An is normal but it does not satisfy (2).

Dihedral Group also works here as example.